# Issues with fstream and eof() (have spent a combined 5 hours debugging, searching for a solution, and testing)

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream

```
int i = 0;
while(!fin.eof())
{

    fin >> fname;
    fin >> lname;
    fin >> id;

    customer[i].setFname(fname);
    customer[i].setLname(lname);
    customer[i].setId(id);

    i++;
}
fin.close();
```

When my program gets to the fourth iteration of this while loop (and runs out of text from my input .txt file) visual studio prompts me with this:

Unhandled exception at 0x754bc41f in program5.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::ios_base::failure at memory location 0x003ceb64..

I'm clueless as to why. I've tried replacing !fin.eof() with (fin >> x) where x is an int, I've tried a do-while instead of a while, I've tried using get, getline. I thought it might be an issue that eof wasn't triggering with my >> operator so I added fin.peek(); at the very end of the loop so it would trigger eof when it peeked. I just have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Assume my customer class works properly, I've tested outside of this loop at it works perfectly.

Comment: Spend some time on this website. There are *hundreds* of questions, answers and comments telling you that *using `eof()` is always an error and doesn't do what you think*.

Comment: I've spent hours on this site and still haven't resolved my issue, care to refer me to a specific post? Even if this is the case why did my other debugging attempts not work? fin >> x, etc

Comment: Use `while (fin >> fname >> lname >> id)`

Comment: You are expecting `eof()` to predict the future.

Comment: still identical issue occurs with your suggestion 0x499602D2

Comment: @DavidSchwartz yes I thought that might be an issue, it won't trigger, so why did adding an fin.peek(); at the end not trigger it?

Comment: @StefanTheard: It's hard to debug code you can't see.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall, one of the idioms when working with streams is to make loops like

```
while (cin >> x){
   //do something...
```

You should be checking the state of the stream while you read in the values.  You could do something like

```
while(fin >> fname && fin >> lname && fin >> id){
...
```

This could probably be made more elegant